# Connecting VPN clients with VPC peering in between

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc

**Situation**

- I have a VPN Server running on VPC-A. IP 10.10.39.198
- I have multiple VPN Clients connected on VPN Server. All clients have IPs in the 172.16.0.0/15 range
- I have an APP Server running on VPC-B.

I now need to communicate between the App Server and a VPN client.

**What have I done**

- Setup VPC Peering connection between VPC-A and VPC-B
- Setup routing tables between VPC-A and VPC-B. VPC-B is configured to route 172.16.0.0/15 to VPC-A

**What works**

- VPN Server can ping the VPN clients
- App Server can ping the VPN Server.

And there is where I am stranded now. The App server can't reach the clients of the VPN Server.

Traceroute stays dark (only starts). While a traceroute to the VPN server is ok. What exactly am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have here is transitive routing. When trying to go from the app in VPC B to the clients, you're transiting VPC A. By default, this won't work.

What you can do is set up a transit gateway and configure the routing appropriately from there. VPC A would be your transit hub, and VPC B would be a spoke.

Comment: I would not expect this to work, unless there is a piece of the puzzle that I'm overlooking, because the VPN user IP addresses are working in their home VPC due to entries in the routing table(s) for that VPC's subnets, pointing to the ENI of the VPN server. I see no way to accomplish that same routing entry in the transit gateway, since routing that block to that VPC still doesn't get it all the way back to that ENI.  It's still edge-to-edge, like trying to "share" a NAT Gateway among multiple VPCs, which also wouldn't work with a transit gateway (for the same reason it doesn't with peering).